# Android custom listview with checkbox detect if no checkbox is checked

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have a menu item wherein if it is clicked I need to check first if a checkbox is checked. If not then display a toast message.

This is what I've tried so far:

**On menu item click:**

```
 SparseBooleanArray checkedPositions = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
            int size = checkedPositions.size();
            for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
                // We get the key stored at the index 'i'
                int key = checkedPositions.keyAt(i);
                // We get the boolean value with the key
                Log.i ("SavedItems", "checkedPositions(" + key + ") = " + checkedPositions.get(key));
            }

            if(size < 1) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No item selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

This is working if no checkbox is checked but if I check and uncheck it's not firing the toast message. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean `if I check and uncheck it's not firing the toast message` ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK if I check the checkbox and then uncheck

Comment: Toast message is not displayed.

Comment: No, I don't get that message.

Comment: what is value in size?

Comment: I'm getting size = 1

Comment: you are not showing any toast inside `for` loop and also try to use `checkedPositions.get(i)` which print status in log

Comment: Yes I updated that. But when activity is loaded for first time and you have no action done on checkboxes, it's not displaying toast message. I need to display message

Comment: @be tty: then check what value you are getting in `size` when activity is loaded for first time?

Comment: Thanks it's working now. I just added aif(!checkedPositions.get(key)) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No item selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }  inside for loop

Comment: Use `checkedPositions.indexOfValue` to check is value is available or not instead of for loop

Answer (score 0):

To show Message accoding to if any item is checked or not in ListView use `SparseBooleanArray.indexOfValue` which will return  index of checked item otherwise return `-1` :

```
SparseBooleanArray checkedPositions = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
int isItemChecked=checkedPositions.indexOfValue(true);

if(isItemChecked>0){
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ItemChecked : " +isItemChecked +
         " Value :"+checkedPositions.get(isItemChecked), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No item selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: It's still displaying no item selected when I checked an item